# datetimepicker Jquery not working on asp textbox but working on html control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have downloaded bootstrap admin template from google to use in my web application.

Now I want to use `datetimepicker` using `jquery` on `asp:textbox`

Here is html control on which `jquery` is applied

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="02-16-2012" id="dp1" />
```

this works fine when I click on this control it pop up date time picker

but now I want to use this on my `textbox`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB"    CssClass="form-control" runat="server"  />
```

but I didn't find any java script calling method from html control such that I add it to my asp control. I even change ID of asp `textbox` to `dp1` but it didn't work.

---

**Solution:**

I just give link of new `jquery` and deleted old one. now it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

use a common class on textbox to call date picker. Add this script in a common place and only use a common class in the textboxes wher ever you want to open date picker

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB"    CssClass="form-control DatePick" runat="server"  />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        _fn_date_picker();
    });

 function _fn_date_picker() {
        $(".DatePick").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", yearRange:"1900:2200", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true, onSelect: function() { this.fireEvent && this.fireEvent('onchange') || $(this).change(); } });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have u used jQuery Main plugin, jquery-Ui plugin and css before this??
<script src="Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery-ui.css"></script>
<script src="Js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: along with document.ready u can write one more bellow that
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {_fn_date_picker();
}
Once check. if not working now. then plz comment the error u are geting in console window

Comment: Yes i used it and i am sure because when i use html control then i works but not in asp: texbox

Comment: then u can use HTML input type="text" with ID and runat="server". and u can retrive value in code behind like Id.Value

Answer (score 1):

May be the ID of the textbox isn't `txtDOB`it might be `ctrl00-ucDatePicker-txtDOB` or something as asp.net generate the IDs on the fly.

I think you should try with class

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtDOB" CssClass="form-control date-picker" runat="server" />
```

then apply use a class selector rather than an ID selector `txtDOB`

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker();
```

or you can try a partial ID picker

```
$("input[id*=txtDOB]").datepicker();
```

Comment: then you sure you have jQuery UI library installed

Comment: yes i am sure because when i use html control in my web page it open datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

Either use it with class name:

```
$(".form-control").datetimepicker();
```

or make use of `Control.ClientID`:

```
$("#<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>").datetimepicker();
```

Because asp changes the id of each element dynamically attaching some random numbers to it. So, `<%=txtDOB.ClientID %>` will let you get that id.

---

### Noticed:

You are mentioning to use `datetimepicker` but you are initializing `datepicker`.

Comment: I followed your instructions too but not working yet

Comment: @Waqas make sure your dom is ready before initializing this datepicker. so you can wrap it within the doc ready block.

Comment: @Waqas what is it `datetimepicker` or `datetpicker`?